# How to find the IP of the source of an SSH reverse tunnel?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

Using `lsof -i` I can see there is a reverse ssh tunnel set up on my server:

```
sshd       1321   remote    8u  IPv4 219299       TCP localhost.localdomain:mvs-capacity (LISTEN)
```

How can I find out the IP address of the machine that created this tunnel?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`lsof -nPp 1321`

Answer (score 1):

Run `lsof -i | grep 1321` to see the other connections the pid has, one of which should be the ip of the machine that created the tunnel.

Answer (score 1):

or you can use netstat -a

Answer (score 0):

Try `netstat -ntp | grep 1321` (replace 1321 with the pid of the process in question.). This will allow you to see the network connections.

Answer (score 0):

To get only the ip address you can do this.

```
netstat -ntp | grep "27750" | awk '{print $5}' | awk -F ':' '{print $1}'
```

If you know that you only have one tunnel you can use this without knowledge of the pid.

```
netstat -ntp | grep "sshd: root" | awk '{print $5}' | awk -F ':' '{print $1}'
```

Comment: Remember that `netstat` is deprecated and may not be installed on modern Linux systems.