# How to get reverse tunnel IP

Tags: ssh, ip, tunnel

I created reverse tunnel from Server to Endpoint using command:

```
ssh -R 127.0.0.1:4000:localhost:81 user@server.domain
```

Tunnel was created on Endpoint side and it leads from Server port 4000 to Endpoint port 81. There is a service listening on this port but this is not important. I did it so because Endpoint is behind NAT and I needed to get access to it from outside.

I wonder if I can get the IP of the Endpoint on the Server side. There was a similar question:

[How to find the IP of the source of an SSH reverse tunnel?](https://serverfault.com/questions/178930/how-to-find-the-ip-of-the-source-of-an-ssh-reverse-tunnel)

but my case is specific. I don't want to manually enter commands because there will be many reverse tunnels to the Server and I can use only the port which Endpoint is bound to.

**In other words: how to get tunnel IP of the Endpoint side using only the port 4000 on the Server side?** I'm not able to find any correlation between the port 4000 on Server with established SSH connection for tunnel purposes.

netstat -plant (on the Server) shows:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30307/sshd: user
tcp        0      0 8.8.8.8:22              1.2.3.4:44874           ESTABLISHED 12531/sshd: user
tcp        0      0 8.8.8.8:22              15.16.17.18:44258       ESTABLISHED 30203/sshd: user
tcp        0      0 8.8.8.8:22              22.22.22.22:46696       ESTABLISHED 15639/sshd: user
```

As you can see there is a service listening on port 4000 (this port is forwarded to Endpoint port 81 - which is not visible here) and three ssh connections. One of them serves the tunnel. But I don't know which one. 8.8.8.8 is the IP of the Server.

Comment: The obvious answer is `who am i`

Comment: I wish it gave me the IP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the process id of ssh from the netstat,

```
lsof -p $pid -a -d 3
```

will show IP of other end of the connection. As ssh can be hopped, this might not be the final location.

Comment: Yes, it shows me the tunnel ssh connection. But can you explain me what does

    -d 3

stand for? I know it's a file descriptor but what does third (3) descriptor mean?

Comment: It just happens to be what the sshd child process inherits as the active connection from its parent when its forks off.

Comment: OK, thanks. Just to expand a little your answer, there is an option **-n** which changes domain names into IP addresses. Would you, please, expand your answer? Cheers.